# How to save output of following program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help me with following function program:

=========================================

```
print("Function program to ad students")

students = []


def get_student_name():
    student_name = []
    for student in students:
        student_name = student.name()
    return student_name


def print_student_name():
    student_name = get_student_name()
    print(student_name)


def add_student(name, id1):
    student = {"Name": name, "ID": id1}
    students.append(student)


def save_file(student):
    try:
        file = open("students.txt", "a")
        file.write(student + "\n")
        file.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Not saved")

def read_file():
    try:
        file = open("students.txt", "r")
        for student in file.readlines():
            add_student(student)
        file.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Not read")


read_file()
print(students)

Des = input("Enter yes or no: ")

while Des == "yes":
    add_student(name=input("Enter name: "), id1=input("Enter ID: "))
    print(students)
    Des = input("Enter yes or no: ")

print("outside loop")

save_file(students)
```

=========================================

The file is not getting saved, i think its an issue with line number 9 in first function i.e. {student_name = student.name()}

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. First, in the `read_file` you call the function `add_student` with one parameter (while 2 required). Next, in the `save_file` you add a string (`"\n"`) to the dictionary (the parameter `student` happens to be a dictionary).

Try to cleanup your code, you would find even more. For example you use the list `students` where you expect the single student dict, etc...

Answer (score 0):

following is the program which worked:

====================================
print("Function program to ad students")

students = {}

def get_student_name():
    student_name = {}
    for student in students:
        student_name = student.name()
    return student_name

def print_student_name():
    student_name = get_student_name()
    print(student_name)

def add_student(name, id1):
    student = {name: id1}
    students.update(student)

def save_file(student):
    try:
        file = open("students.txt", "a")
        file.write(str(student))
        file.close()
    except Exception as ex1:
        print("Not saved.  Error: ", ex1)

def read_file():
    try:
        file = open("students.txt", "r")
        for student in file.readlines():
            print(student)
        file.close()
    except Exception as ex2:
        print("Not read. Error: ", ex2)

read_file()
print(students)

Des = input("Enter yes or no: ")

while Des == "yes":
    add_student(name=input("Enter name: "), id1=input("Enter ID: "))
    print(students)
    Des = input("Enter yes or no: ")

print("outside loop")

## save_file(students)

It still can be improved allot though. Displaying exception message helped though.

Thank you Dmitry Kuzminov